# .net core test not showing correctly in VS 2015 Test Explorer

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2015, .net-core

I am trying to build unit tests for my dotnet core project using xunit following these steps outlined here https://xunit.github.io/docs/getting-started-dotnet-core.html

The problem I have is that any updates to the the unit tests are not reflected in VS 2015 Test Explorer. I have tried building the solution and then running the tests, but it's still not showing up or it's using the old build.

If I run the tests from the command line using "dotnet test", then everything works fine. When I go to the Test Explorer here after, it shows the updated and new unit tests. But I can't get the same to work in VS Test Explorer.

What I do now is, go to the command line, run "dotnet test", go back to VS and "Run All" from the Test Explorer to get the view updated with the new test results.

It seems that doing the build in VS and selecting "Run All" doesn't affect the assemblies used by the Test Explorer.

Can you help me get everything working from VS itself?

I am using Visual Studio 2015 Update 3.

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into the same problem today: disable the test settings if you have any loaded. After that they started successfully showing up for me.

Comment: I don't have any test settings loaded. This is a clean project. I just followed the article to add xunit and build my first tests.